# Using another developers enterprise account

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-id

I have a Cordova iOS app that is all complete and running as it should using a development provisioning profile distributed via diawi.

I have just found out the client needs the app today but they also need to distribute it to a lot of iPads (too many to collect udids) so previously they have used the ad hoc method with the previous developers enterprise account.

Now, I have applied for the enterprise account, but I fear that's going to take a long time to organise (I do already have a duns number though).

I have found another developer who already has an enterprise account and is willing to build the app for me to distribute to my client.

I would like to know what are the pitfalls of this - what's the worst that can happen and is there any other option?

Thanks!
Lee

Comment: The worst that can happen is that apple deletes the account of the other developer for distributing enterprise apps to people outside his enterprise

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute application with application with another developer's enterprise account. You need to get initial of Bundle ID for that profile. You can make app with Command + B and then make zip file and upload to Diawi.

Without enterprise profile, it is not possible to install application in any device.